# Looping Variables Through Array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I created some arrays and I want to post data to them and loop through the new data to make a new object. Please find the code below. The commented out for statement at the bottom does what I expect but it returns the same data. Since I'm using the same variable names, I believe all I need to do is save them to wherever (right now I was thinking localstorage) unless there is another way to perform this. Any ideas are appreciated.

Essentially, I need to separate the userInput(Based On numInd) because that is the driving force behind all the other code.

```
        /* # of Indicators */
        var numInd = 2 ;

        /*DOM Variables*/
        /*User Entry*/
        /*Index/Object 1 */
        var curInd = 1 ;
        var oWidth = 200
        var oHeight = 125
        var oCaptionValue = "'Object 1'"
        var oFontSize = 16
        var oDataType = 1 /*Type Of Indicator*/
        var oDataIndex = 205 /*Index Of DataType*/
        var oTrueColor = 5751415 /*Need Converter Here*/
        var oFalseColor = 2498528 /*Need Converter Here*/
        var oBorder = 2
        var oBackColor = 5000527 /*Need Converter Here*/

        /*Index/Object 2 */
        var curInd = 2 ;
        var oWidth = 200
        var oHeight = 125
        var oCaptionValue = "'Object 2'"
        var oFontSize = 16
        var oDataType = 1 /*Type Of Indicator*/
        var oDataIndex = 210 /*Index Of DataType*/
        var oTrueColor = 5751415 /*Need Converter Here*/
        var oFalseColor = 2498528 /*Need Converter Here*/
        var oBorder = 2
        var oBackColor = 5000527 /*Need Converter Here*/


        var userInput = [oWidth, oHeight, oCaptionValue, oFontSize, oDataType, oDataIndex, oTrueColor, oFalseColor, oBorder, oBackColor];
        var out = [] ;
        for (i = 0; i < numInd; i++ ) {
          out.push(userInput)
        }
        var ueArr = out[curInd]
        console.log(out)


        /*Object Variables*/
        var strDivStart = '<div class="col-sm-auto pt-3">'
        var strObjectStart = '<object classid="clsid:71060668-0E45-11D3-81B6-0000E206D650" id="FRIPToggleLamp1" style="width: ' + ueArr[0] +'px; height: ' + ueArr[1] +'px">'
        var strCaption = '<param name="Caption" value=' + ueArr[2] + '>'
        var strFontSize = '<param name="FontSize" value=' + ueArr[3] + '>'
        var strDataType = '<param name="DataType" value=' + ueArr[4] + '>'
        var strDataIndex = '<param name="DataIndex" value=' + ueArr[5] + '>'
        var strTrueColor = '<param name="TrueColor" value=' + ueArr[6] + '>'
        var strFalseColor = '<param name="FalseColor" value=' + ueArr[7] + '>'
        var strInterval = '<param name="Interval" value="250" />'
        var strTrueFont = '<param name="TrueFont" value="-1" />'
        var strFastLoad = '<param name="FastLoad" value="-1" />'
        var strPeriodic = '<param name="Periodic" value="-1" />'
        var strBorder = '<param name="Border" value=' + ueArr[8] + '>'
        var strBackColor = '<param name="BackColor" value=' + ueArr[9] + '>'
        var strObjectEnd = '</object>'
        var strDivEnd = '</div>'
        var objectValue = [strDivStart, strObjectStart, strCaption, strFontSize, strDataType, strDataIndex, strTrueColor, strFalseColor, strInterval,  strTrueFont, strFastLoad, strPeriodic, strBorder, strBackColor, strObjectEnd, strDivEnd];
        var out = [] ;
        for (i = 0; i < numInd; i++ ) {
          out.push(objectValue)
        }
        var ovArr = out[curInd]
        console.log(out)


        /*Number Of Indicators To Show?*/
        var activeX = document.getElementById("errorIndicator") ;
        var out = [] ;
        var indVars = ovArr[0] + ovArr[1] + ovArr[2] + ovArr[3] + ovArr[4] + ovArr[5] + ovArr[6] + ovArr[7] + ovArr[8] +  ovArr[9] + ovArr[10] + ovArr[11] + ovArr[12] + ovArr[13] + ovArr[14] + ovArr[15] ;
        out.push(indVars)
        /*for (i = 0; i < numInd; i++) {
          out.push(indVars)
        }
        console.log(out)*/
        activeX.innerHTML = out.join("")
```

Comment: When would you expect these values to change exactly?

Comment: I am planning on creating another page that uses this script as a back end. So the user inputs data or dropdown or whatever, and the user input data gets posted to the variables...I was thinking var oWidth = localstorage.getItem or something like that. The problem I run into is that userInput is looking at oWidth and oWidth value will change depending on numInd.